# Bootstrap theme customization

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to ensure that the month and year fields on a payment page always line up on the same line to ensure consistency regardless of device but using bootstrap I have been unable to achieve it thus far:

A jsfiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ta7eea42/1/) for the following HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2 bold" for="Expiry_Date">Expiry Date</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <select style="height:49px;border-radius:4px;margin-bottom:15px;" name="ccmonth" class="form-control input">
                                <option value="13" selected="">Month</option>
                                <option value="01">01-Jan</option>
                                <option value="02">02-Feb</option>
                                <option value="03">03-Mar</option>
                                <option value="04">04-Apr</option>
                                <option value="05">05-May</option>
                                <option value="06">06-Jun</option>
                                <option value="07">07-Jul</option>
                                <option value="08">08-Aug</option>
                                <option value="09">09-Sep</option>
                                <option value="10">10-Oct</option>
                                <option value="11">11-Nov</option>
                                <option value="12">12-Dec</option>
                            </select>
                            <select style="height:49px;border-radius:4px;" id="pas_ccyear" name="ccyear" class="form-control input">
                                <option value="1">Year</option>
                                <option value="15">2015</option>
                                <option value="16">2016</option>
                                <option value="17">2017</option>
                                <option value="18">2018</option>
                                <option value="19">2019</option>
                                <option value="20">2020</option>
                                <option value="21">2021</option>
                                <option value="22">2022</option>
                                <option value="23">2023</option>
                                <option value="24">2024</option>
                                <option value="25">2025</option>
                                <option value="26">2026</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

If I set the with to 49.6% for each of the selects it lines up correctly on desktop screen but still wont show consistently on same line for mobile and tablet

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine?

Comment: Can you describe what happens when it's not working correctly?

Comment: when i minimize the screen to replicate another device size the year select drops to another line below the month select, this is the same on mobile device

Answer (score 0):

What if you try wrapping each of your selects within a div with the class "col-xs-6" that way even on the smallest screens each select will only ever get half of the available width from the "col-md-10" parent div.

Comment: unfortunately that was not the case, I had thought this first